# SOAP-Server C++/Delphi: How can I clear previous authentication?

Tags: c++, delphi, http-authentication

I have a SOAP-Server (created with WebServer Wizard in C++Builder 10.3).

I use HTTP Basic Authentication to login. I can see and check user/password either in `TIdHTTPWebBrokerBridge::OnParseAuthentication()` or in `TWebModule::WebModule1DefaultHandlerAction()`, like this:

```cpp
void __fastcall TForm1::OnParseAuthentication(TIdContext *AContext, const UnicodeString AAuthType,
    const UnicodeString AAuthData, UnicodeString& VUsername, UnicodeString& VPassword, bool& VHandled)
{
    String szZugangsdaten = TNetEncoding::Base64->Decode(AAuthData);

    System::DynamicArray<System::UnicodeString> array = ::SplitString(szZugangsdaten, ":");

    if (array.Length == 2) {
        VUsername = array[0];
        VPassword = array[1];
        VHandled = bool(VUsername == "right_user" && VPassword == "right_pw");
    }
    else {
        VHandled = false;
    }
}
```

My problem is that as soon as the client logs in, the old ("correct") access data is always transmitted in the response, even if I enter incorrect user/password in the browser:

1. attempt: http://wrong_user:wrong_pw@myserver.com -> No authentication (OK)
2. attempt: http://richt_user:right_pw@myserver.com -> Authentication (OK)
3. attempt: http://wrong_user:wrong_pw@myserver.com -> Authentication (!!!)

How can I avoid this?

Comment: `TIdCustomHTTPServer` parses `BASIC` credentials for you, into the `AuthExists`/`AuthUsername`/`AuthPassword` properties of `TIdHTTPRequestInfo`. I don't know how WebBroker works, but you are not supposed to *validate* credentials in the `OnParseAuthentication` event, only *parse* them. Set `VHandled` to whether *parsing* is ok or not. *Validate* the parsed credentials in the `OnCommand...` events. However, the parsed credentials are not accessible by `TWebRequest`, but the `Authentication` header is, so move your parsing out of `OnParseAuthentication` into your WebRequest handler.

Comment: [This article](https://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/en/showarticle.php?id=2) shows how to do HTML-based authentication with WebBroker.  I have no idea how to do HTTP-based authentication with it.  I think that is handled by whatever HTTP server your WebBroker in running in (ISS, Apache, etc).

Comment: If you tested via a browser: probably the browser cached the credentials.

Comment: Hi, Remy, thank you for answer.

Comment: Yes, if I check user/passwort in WebModuleDefaultHandlerAction() , it works with SAP now. My problem was really credentials cache on browser, thank you Oliver for this idea.